# Рекурсия в алгоритме быстрой сортировки (Java)

Tags: java, сортировка, qsort

Есть сам алгоритм, но вопрос такой: когда отсортирована первая половина массива(левая часть, та что меньше пивота) он по идее должен выйти из метода так как не срабатывают оба условия

```
if (left < j)
        qs(items, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        qs(items, i, right);
```

но он назад запрыгивает во второй if и каким то образом дает значение i = 3 и начинает сортировать вторую половину. Вопрос в том как он это понял? или это особенность рекурсивного вызова?

**вот сам код**:

class Quicksort {

```
// Организовать вызов фактического метода быстрой сортировки
static void qsort(int[] items) {
    qs(items, 0, items.length - 1);
}

// Рекурсивная версия метода быстрой сортировки символов
private static void qs(int[] items, int left, int right) {

    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int pivot, TEMP;

    pivot = items[(left + right) / 2];

    do {

        while ((items[i] < pivot) && (i < right)) i++;
        while ((pivot < items[j] && (j > left))) j--;

        if (i <= j) {
            TEMP = items[i];
            items[i] = items[j];
            items[j] = TEMP;
            i++; j--;
        }

    } while (i <= j);

    if (left < j)
        qs(items, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        qs(items, i, right);
}
```

}

public class QSDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = {17, -24, 20, -15, -21, -3, 13};

    System.out.println("Исходный массив: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();

    // Отсоритровать массив
    Quicksort.qsort(a);

    System.out.println("Отсортированный массив: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не сработают оба условия?
Это может произойти только при малой длине диапазона - 1 или 2

Умозрительно для данного массива и указанного выбора разделителя процесс пойдёт так:

```
 17, -24, 20, -15, -21, -3, 13
 после первого partition
-21, -24, -15, 20, 17, -3, 13
```

Теперь обрабатываются оба поддиапазона 0..2 и 3..6. Сначала первый if делает рекурсивный вызов на поддиапазоне 0..2, сортируется первая половина. Только после этого происходит выход на первый уровень рекурсии, где всё ещё left=0,right=6, и срабатывает второй if
Последовательность рекурсивных вызовов будет такой (значения left, right, уровень (глубина) рекурсии):

```
0 6    1
0 2    2
1 2    3
3 6    2 
3 4    3 
5 6    3
```

Comment: ты не понял! алгоритм рабочий! как он назначает i значение 3 и начинает сортировать дальше???? ты в отладчике прогони поэтапно и поймешь. когда первая часть до пивота отсортирована он не заходит не в один не во второй if, а спускается к фигурной скобке конца метода и типо должен из него выйти, но этого не происходит! он запрыгивает в итоге во второй if  и дает значение i = 3! как он этот второй диапазон 3...6 получает?

Comment: На каком уровне рекурсии, при каких left, right это происходит?

Comment: когда i = 2 right = 2 left = 1! В этот момент он не проходит ни одно условие и встает у фигурной скобки конца метода и когда нажимаешь идти дальше, он в итоге запрыгивает на второе условие с параметрами i = 3, right = 6, left = 0. Я то понимаю как этот алгоритм работает, но не могу понять как компьютер получил эти числа

Comment: Я добавил описание рекурсивных вызовов

Comment: Понял!! Спасибо!

Comment: Так оно осталось с самого первого уровня

Comment: Надо рекурсию получше изучить))